# regex match <cms:xxx /> custom html tag

Tags: php, regex

I am developing own CMS and need to replace custom tags with proper php function.
my custom tags are like `<cms:zone id="header" anotherAttr="attrValue" />` the `<cms:xxx />` part is important to me.
so far i wrote this regex but its not working fine. `<cms:?([\S|\s]*)\/>`

```
<body>
        <cms:content id="footer" />

        <cms:zone id="header" />

</body>
```

**it will match**

```
<cms:content id="footer" />

            <cms:zone id="header" />
```

Comment: Why not use a proper DOM parser?

Comment: I'm using a framework with template compiler class which is my need and I just modifying it to my own purpose. beside i heard this method is faster but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the quantifier not greedy:

```
<cms:?([\S\s]*?)\/>
       here __^
```

and there're no needs for `|` inside the character class